# Convert negative prediction output to zero in azure machine learning

Tags: sql, azure-machine-learning-service

In azure machine learning experiment, i am getting negative predictions. i want to replace my all negative prediction with zero. I do not have programming skills so i am using SQL transformation.

after score model module i used SQL Transformation with following query

```
select [Scored Labels] from t1;

update t1
set [Scored Labels] = '0'
where [Scored Labels] < '0' ;
```

it works in SQL Server Management Studio but not in azure machine learning. i did not get error and it gave input as output without changing anything.

is there any error? how do i replace negative values with zero?

Comment: can you include a [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're almost there! The Apply SQL Transformation module still outputs a result dataset, so try switching your statements around:

```
update t1 
set [Scored Labels] = 0
where [Scored Labels] < 0;

select * from t1;
```

See how that works. :)